# i get error omniauth: (stripe_connect) Authentication failure! invalid_credentials: OAuth2::Error, invalid_client: No such API key: Bearer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, stripe-payments

i tested my app locally and works fine, but then i deployed it to Heroku and no im running into issues. 
i get this error after i skip the form for redirection:
ERROR -- omniauth: (stripe_connect) Authentication failure! invalid_credentials: OAuth2::Error,

This is what my files look like

using gem figaro for handling the keys.

application.yml:

```
STRIPE_SECRET: sk_test_*************** STRIPE_CONNECT_CLIENT_ID: ca_**************
```

omniauth.rb:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do provider :stripe_connect, ENV['STRIPE_CONNECT_CLIENT_ID'], ENV['STRIPE_SECRET'] end
```

secrets.yml:

```
STRIPE_SECRET: sk_test_*************** STRIPE_CONNECT_CLIENT_ID: ca_**************
```

Comment: Did you execute the figaro command to set values from your configuration file on heroku ?    

$ figaro heroku:set -e production

Comment: no i did not, let me do that. so just `figaro heroku:set -e production`?

Comment: Yes, run this from console.